# How to use RxJava instead of AsyncTask to load data?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, rx-java2

I am using AsyncTask for loading data, data comes from server, but due to so much data I want to load data on a background thread.

Here is my code

```
  private void loadData() {

  new AsyncTask<Void, ArrayList<DataModel>, ArrayList<DataModel>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            DialogHelper.showProgress(MyActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<DataModel> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {

                return MyParser.parseData(jsonDataAsResultFromServer);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DataModel> list) {
            super.onPostExecute(list);

            DialogHelper.hideProgress();

            if (list.size() > 0) {

                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this);
                myAdapter.addAll(list);
                recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);              
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

}

Comment: look up Retrofit and RxJava2 Adapter tutorial. Retrofit is a type safe HTTP client and by using the RxJava2 Adapter, network calls from Retrofit will become reactive. After that you can use Moshi to help you with json serialization.
Besides, RxJava2 is about reactive programming, not actually about making network calls, consider learning RxJava2 itself too. It can make Android development easier.